# blur() event is not working on IPAD and Iphone

Tags: javascript, css

I have tried `blur()` for replacing the css but that function is not working. I did research on it that `blur()` is not work for IOS device. Is there any other way to remove `position` from `.body-clip-overflow` when focus is out from input field. My code is attached below. [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/munni/h9Lr54cp/4/)

```
$(document).on('focus', 'input, textarea', function() {
   $('.body-clip-overflow').css('position', 'fixed');
   $('.ui-dialog').css('position', 'absolute');
   $('.ui-dialog').css('top', '80px');
 });

$(document).on('blur', 'input, textarea', function() {
   setTimeout(function() {
      $('.body-clip-overflow').css('position', 'relative');
   }, 100);
});
```

Comment: [`blur`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event) seems to be supported. Maybe the issue is, that `blur` doesn't bubble (jQuery should take care of that, though). Try with [`focusout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focusout_event).

Comment: @Teemu i have tried with focusout but not work for me

Comment: Are you sure the event is not fired? Have you tested it with the console?

Comment: @Teemu yes i have checked in the console. focusout is not working only for iPad but its triggered on iPad pro https://www.screencast.com/t/4CfKCGlFvk

Comment: iphone 6/7/8 have same problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).live('blur', function () {
   //some code
});
```

or try 'keyup':

```
$(document).live('keyup', function () {
    //some code
});
```

Comment: the question didnt had version mentioned

Comment: try keyup instead of blur